# Appium driver initialization fails on OSX machine with "JAVA_HOME is not set"

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

Despite the fact that I presumably have my variables declared correctly in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/michaelcas/Library/Android/sdk
ANDROID_HOME=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}
```

whenever I try to initialize an Android driver on my OSX machine, Appium throws this error

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME

and when I run Appium doctor I get everything is okay, and that JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

```
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 11.1.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/michaelcas
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /Users/michaelcas/Library/Android/sdk
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: /Users/michaelcas/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: /Users/michaelcas/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: /Users/michaelcas/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is set
```

**edit**

When I do

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and Appium Doctor Java Home is

```
✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Can you check that 
Path 1 - info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home
Path 2 - JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) in bashprofile
points to same location ?

Comment: @AmitJain I add the output of the `echo $JAVA_HOME` to the bottom of my post, so it does appear that `bashprofile` and `AppiumDoctor` point to the same location.